# IF statement not changing outcome of variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I currently have this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

like = "like";
current_likes = parseInt(50);
    $("#add-love").click(function(){
        if(like = "like"){
            $("#my_like").removeClass('hidden-profile');
            current_likes++;
            $("#like_count").html(current_likes);
            like = "unlike";
            console.log(like);
        }else{
            $("#my_like").addClass('hidden-profile');
            current_likes--;
            $("#like_count").html(current_likes);
            like = "like";
        }
    });
});
```

But when i click the like button, it updates the like counter and also the variable (i have checked this by logging it) But when it is clicked the second time it doesnt fall into the second part of the if statement, rather it just acts as if like="like" still?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're assigning `=`, rather than comparing `==`.

```
if(like = "like"){
// Should be
if(like == "like"){
//------^^^
```

Note that you have declared the variable `like` to `window` scope, since you didn't use the `var` keyword. If it should be scoped only to the `ready()` function, use `var like = 'like';` inside the `ready()` function.  If you do intend it at `window` scope, it is advisable to use the `var` keyword outside the `ready()` function.

```
// Declare at higher scope
var like;  
$(document).ready(function(){
  // And access in the function...
  like = "like";
  current_likes = parseInt(50);
  //etc...
  //etc...
});
```

Comment: You do not know how big of'a fool i feel. I remember doing this back when i was learning PHP. You sire, are a saint.